# How to change the prev and next text button to image next/prev

Tags: jquery, pagination

How to change the prev and next text button to image next/prev. I just want to replace next/prev text button to image of prev and next. Can someone help me? Thank you!
My sample code is for pagination. I just want next and prev image button instead text button.

```js
(function($){
 var methods = {
  init: function(options) {
   var o = $.extend({
    items: 1,
    itemsOnPage: 1,
    pages: 0,
    displayedPages: 5,
    edges: 2,
    currentPage: 0,
    hrefTextPrefix: '#page-',
    hrefTextSuffix: '',
    prevText: 'Prev',
    nextText: 'Next',
    ellipseText: '&hellip;',
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    listStyle: '',
    labelMap: [],
    selectOnClick: true,
    nextAtFront: false,
    invertPageOrder: false,
    useStartEdge : true,
    useEndEdge : true,
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber, event) {
     // Callback triggered when a page is clicked
     // Page number is given as an optional parameter
    },
    onInit: function() {
     // Callback triggered immediately after initialization
    }
   }, options || {});

   var self = this;

   o.pages = o.pages ? o.pages : Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage) ? Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage) : 1;
   if (o.currentPage)
    o.currentPage = o.currentPage - 1;
   else
    o.currentPage = !o.invertPageOrder ? 0 : o.pages - 1;
   o.halfDisplayed = o.displayedPages / 2;

   this.each(function() {
    self.addClass(o.cssStyle + ' simple-pagination').data('pagination', o);
    methods._draw.call(self);
   });

   o.onInit();

   return this;
  },

  selectPage: function(page) {
   methods._selectPage.call(this, page - 1);
   return this;
  },

  prevPage: function() {
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
    if (o.currentPage > 0) {
     methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage - 1);
    }
   } else {
    if (o.currentPage < o.pages - 1) {
     methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage + 1);
    }
   }
   return this;
  },

  nextPage: function() {
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
    if (o.currentPage < o.pages - 1) {
     methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage + 1);
    }
   } else {
    if (o.currentPage > 0) {
     methods._selectPage.call(this, o.currentPage - 1);
    }
   }
   return this;
  },

  getPagesCount: function() {
   return this.data('pagination').pages;
  },

  setPagesCount: function(count) {
   this.data('pagination').pages = count;
  },

  getCurrentPage: function () {
   return this.data('pagination').currentPage + 1;
  },

  destroy: function(){
   this.empty();
   return this;
  },

  drawPage: function (page) {
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   o.currentPage = page - 1;
   this.data('pagination', o);
   methods._draw.call(this);
   return this;
  },

  redraw: function(){
   methods._draw.call(this);
   return this;
  },

  disable: function(){
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   o.disabled = true;
   this.data('pagination', o);
   methods._draw.call(this);
   return this;
  },

  enable: function(){
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   o.disabled = false;
   this.data('pagination', o);
   methods._draw.call(this);
   return this;
  },

  updateItems: function (newItems) {
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   o.items = newItems;
   o.pages = methods._getPages(o);
   this.data('pagination', o);
   methods._draw.call(this);
  },

  updateItemsOnPage: function (itemsOnPage) {
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   o.itemsOnPage = itemsOnPage;
   o.pages = methods._getPages(o);
   this.data('pagination', o);
   methods._selectPage.call(this, 0);
   return this;
  },

  getItemsOnPage: function() {
   return this.data('pagination').itemsOnPage;
  },

  _draw: function() {
   var o = this.data('pagination'),
    interval = methods._getInterval(o),
    i,
    tagName;

   methods.destroy.call(this);
   
   tagName = (typeof this.prop === 'function') ? this.prop('tagName') : this.attr('tagName');

   var $panel = tagName === 'UL' ? this : $('<ul' + (o.listStyle ? ' class="' + o.listStyle + '"' : '') + '></ul>').appendTo(this);

   // Generate Prev link
   if (o.prevText) {
    methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage - 1 : o.currentPage + 1, {text: o.prevText, classes: 'prev'});
   }

   // Generate Next link (if option set for at front)
   if (o.nextText && o.nextAtFront) {
    methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {text: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
   }

   // Generate start edges
   if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
    if (interval.start > 0 && o.edges > 0) {
     if(o.useStartEdge) {
      var end = Math.min(o.edges, interval.start);
      for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
       methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
      }
     }
     if (o.edges < interval.start && (interval.start - o.edges != 1)) {
      $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
     } else if (interval.start - o.edges == 1) {
      methods._appendItem.call(this, o.edges);
     }
    }
   } else {
    if (interval.end < o.pages && o.edges > 0) {
     if(o.useStartEdge) {
      var begin = Math.max(o.pages - o.edges, interval.end);
      for (i = o.pages - 1; i >= begin; i--) {
       methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
      }
     }

     if (o.pages - o.edges > interval.end && (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end != 1)) {
      $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
     } else if (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end == 1) {
      methods._appendItem.call(this, interval.end);
     }
    }
   }

   // Generate interval links
   if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
    for (i = interval.start; i < interval.end; i++) {
     methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
    }
   } else {
    for (i = interval.end - 1; i >= interval.start; i--) {
     methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
    }
   }

   // Generate end edges
   if (!o.invertPageOrder) {
    if (interval.end < o.pages && o.edges > 0) {
     if (o.pages - o.edges > interval.end && (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end != 1)) {
      $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
     } else if (o.pages - o.edges - interval.end == 1) {
      methods._appendItem.call(this, interval.end);
     }
     if(o.useEndEdge) {
      var begin = Math.max(o.pages - o.edges, interval.end);
      for (i = begin; i < o.pages; i++) {
       methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
      }
     }
    }
   } else {
    if (interval.start > 0 && o.edges > 0) {
     if (o.edges < interval.start && (interval.start - o.edges != 1)) {
      $panel.append('<li class="disabled"><span class="ellipse">' + o.ellipseText + '</span></li>');
     } else if (interval.start - o.edges == 1) {
      methods._appendItem.call(this, o.edges);
     }

     if(o.useEndEdge) {
      var end = Math.min(o.edges, interval.start);
      for (i = end - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       methods._appendItem.call(this, i);
      }
     }
    }
   }

   // Generate Next link (unless option is set for at front)
   if (o.nextText && !o.nextAtFront) {
    methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {text: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
   }
  },

  _getPages: function(o) {
   var pages = Math.ceil(o.items / o.itemsOnPage);
   return pages || 1;
  },

  _getInterval: function(o) {
   return {
    start: Math.ceil(o.currentPage > o.halfDisplayed ? Math.max(Math.min(o.currentPage - o.halfDisplayed, (o.pages - o.displayedPages)), 0) : 0),
    end: Math.ceil(o.currentPage > o.halfDisplayed ? Math.min(o.currentPage + o.halfDisplayed, o.pages) : Math.min(o.displayedPages, o.pages))
   };
  },

  _appendItem: function(pageIndex, opts) {
   var self = this, options, $link, o = self.data('pagination'), $linkWrapper = $('<li></li>'), $ul = self.find('ul');

   pageIndex = pageIndex < 0 ? 0 : (pageIndex < o.pages ? pageIndex : o.pages - 1);

   options = {
    text: pageIndex + 1,
    classes: ''
   };

   if (o.labelMap.length && o.labelMap[pageIndex]) {
    options.text = o.labelMap[pageIndex];
   }

   options = $.extend(options, opts || {});

   if (pageIndex == o.currentPage || o.disabled) {
    if (o.disabled || options.classes === 'prev' || options.classes === 'next') {
     $linkWrapper.addClass('disabled');
    } else {
     $linkWrapper.addClass('active');
    }
    $link = $('<span class="current">' + (options.text) + '</span>');
   } else {
    $link = $('<a href="' + o.hrefTextPrefix + (pageIndex + 1) + o.hrefTextSuffix + '" class="page-link">' + (options.text) + '</a>');
    $link.click(function(event){
     return methods._selectPage.call(self, pageIndex, event);
    });
   }

   if (options.classes) {
    $link.addClass(options.classes);
   }

   $linkWrapper.append($link);

   if ($ul.length) {
    $ul.append($linkWrapper);
   } else {
    self.append($linkWrapper);
   }
  },

  _selectPage: function(pageIndex, event) {
   var o = this.data('pagination');
   o.currentPage = pageIndex;
   if (o.selectOnClick) {
    methods._draw.call(this);
   }
   return o.onPageClick(pageIndex + 1, event);
  }

 };

 $.fn.pagination = function(method) {

  // Method calling logic
  if (methods[method] && method.charAt(0) != '_') {
   return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
   return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
  } else {
   $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pagination');
  }

 };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        prevText: '<img src="../prv.png"/>', // add image for prev button
        nextText: '<img src="../next.png"/>', // add image next button

// Generate Prev link
if (o.prevText) {
    methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage - 1 : o.currentPage + 1, {html: o.prevText, classes: 'prev'});
}

// Generate Next link (if option set for at front)
if (o.nextText && o.nextAtFront) {
    methods._appendItem.call(this, !o.invertPageOrder ? o.currentPage + 1 : o.currentPage - 1, {hmtl: o.nextText, classes: 'next'});
}
```

update following code in `jquery.simplePagination.js`